# Is it possible to import a module and have everything execute within the importing module’s context?

Tags: python, inheritance, module

Suppose I have a package containing two modules `moduleA` and `moduleB`. Both should provide two string manipulation functions as interface `manipulate` and `undo_manipulation`, however they should differ in the details of the manipulation.

Let’s say I want the `manipulate` of `moduleA` to replace all instances of `"i"` with `"u"`, move the first letter to the end and then capitalise the first letter:

```
>>>moduleA.manipulate("string")
'Trungs'
```

In `moduleB` on the other hand it should replace `"r"` with `"w"`, move the first letter to the end, then swap the new first and second letters and then capitalise:

```
>>>moduleB.manipulate("string")
'Wtings'
```

For example I would implement `moduleA` as:

```python
to_replace = {"i": "u"}

def manipulate(string):
    for key, value in to_replace.items():
        string = string.replace(key, value)
    string = move_letter(string)
    return capitalise(string)

def move_letter(string):
    return string[1:]+string[0]

def capitalise(string):
    return string[0].upper()+string[1:]
```

(for the sake of simplicity I’m assuming the input is always at least 3 characters)

Now what I would like to do for `moduleB` is to let it just “inherit” the whole of `moduleA` then override the details (i.e. define a new `to_replaced` and `move_letter`). Then the user should be able to call `moduleB.manipulate` and it would call the imported function, only it would then use the updated context. So basically:

```python
from moduleA import manipulate, move_letter, capitalise
# second import necessary if I want to access the original version of move_letter
from . import moduleA

to_replace{"r": "w"}

def move_letter(string):
    newstring = moduleA.move_letter(string)
    return newstring[1]+newstring[0]+newstring[2:]
```

(Obviously the manipulations I actually want to do are a bit more complex; but they, too, can be broken down into more atomic parts, of which only some should be overridden by the “child” modules)

Unfortunately this doesn’t work. If the user calls `moduleB.manipulate`, it uses `moduleA`’s version of `to_replace` and `move_letter` rather than the updated versions of `moduleB`.

Is there any way around this? Or in other words, is there a way to emulate object inheritance just with modules, without using classes?

I know the behaviour I want can be easily implemented using object inheritance, but both from an interface and a coding point of view it doesn’t feel right to use objects here because:

- the tasks (`manipulate` and `undo_manipulation` which I have left out of the code above for simplicity) both feel much more “verb-y” than “noun-y”.
- there is no changing state whatsoever, so there really is no point to instantiation.
- using an object adds another layer of point-notation which doesn’t really add any new information. So from outside the package the user would have to use at least a three-part name: `package.module.Class` (at least unless they do `from package import...` which also gets cumbersome if they have more than two or three separate modules to import).

For these reasons I would really like to avoid using classes if at all possible. Or if not, I would at least find some way to hide the class layer from the interface to save the user some typing.

Comment: If you really don't want to use a class (I don't think any of your reasons make a strong case against it) you could wrap your function definitions in a factory that gets fed your `to_replace` dict as an argument, which will act as a free variable, then return the functions you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’m afraid being the beginner that I am, I’m not quite sure how you would do that (I only ever encountered factories as returning instances of classes, not functions. Also function objects in general are something I still have to learn a lot about).

I ended up just using classes with only class functions after all, and then simply writing a wrapper for `manipulate` outside of the class. Not as DRY as I’d like since I have to provide that wrapper separately for every module, but there you go :)